# Where is a good landmark to meet a friend in Tallinn, Estonia?

Tags: landmarks, estonia, tallinn

A friend and I are both traveling to Tallinn, separately (me by bus from Riga, he the next day by air) and need to arrange to meet somewhere downtown in the tourist area.

I won't have a working cellphone or equivalent so I'd like to propose meet at some landmark that I can't confuse for somewhere else. Hopefully somewhere simple to get to by public transportation from the airport.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sur if a busy area is the most obvious choice. Why not pick him up at the airport or meet him at the place where you stay?

Answer (score 5):

I think a good place is Viru Square (Viru väljak) it's practically attached to the [Historic Centre](http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/822) and there are several spots, like the Sokos Hotel Viru or the Viru Keskus shopping mall.

From airport there is the [line number 2](http://soiduplaan.tallinn.ee/#bus/2/a-b/13413-3/map/en), bus stop A.Laikmaa, the ticket price is 1.60 €, according to [this page](http://www.tallinn-airport.ee/eng/transport/publictransport)

Answer (score 2):

Within Viru Square, I would arrange to meet at the (Viru) Gate, which is the entrance to the Old Town.